# Почему не отрабатывает правильно в IE и Edge скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. [Есть тестовая страница](http://verstka.test30.ru/test/test2/).

Если "захватить" дни недели и повертеть вправо/влево - будет происходить горизонтальная прокрутка. Но в Edge и IE11 этого не происходит, хотя ошибок в консоле нет.

Сам скрипт:

```
document.onmousedown = function(e) {

    if (e.which != 1) {return;}

    var elem = e.target.closest('#scroll-div');

    if (!elem) return; // не нашли, клик вне draggable-объекта

    $(elem).addClass('moving');

    // запомнить переносимый объект
    dragObject.elem = elem;

    // запомнить координаты, с которых начат перенос объекта
    dragObject.downX = e.pageX;
    dragObject.downY = e.pageY;
    dragObject.moveX = 0;
    dragObject.scrollLeft = elem.scrollLeft;
};

// Сдвигаем на нужную позицию
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (!dragObject.elem) return; // элемент не зажат
    dragObject.elem.scrollLeft = dragObject.scrollLeft - (e.pageX - dragObject.downX);
};

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    $(dragObject.elem).removeClass('moving');
    dragObject = {};
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Плюс почему-то в вышеупомянутых браузеров странно показывается td с текстом "Итого"...

Comment: А на closest не ругается ? http://caniuse.com/#search=closest. Попробуйте заменить этот кусок кода на аналог с jquery

Comment: Думаю вы правы. На closest в EDGE выругался. Заменил на var elem = $(e.target).closest('#scroll-div');. Перестало везде работать

Comment: Вау, я полагал что должно решить проблему, а не усугубить ее =) Тут есть вот такая вот "деталь". "В Internet Explorer у объекта window.event для этого есть свойство srcElement, в остальных браузерах, работающих по рекомендациям W3C, для этого используется event.target." Взять с http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/properties

Comment: Попробуйте использовать проверку на e.target типа "var t = event.target || event.srcElement"

Comment: Во вторых (совет) - раз вы уже используете jquery, то используйте его везде. Или же перепишите все на простой JS. А то получается и так и так =)

Comment: А вообще, может быть, если более простой способ реализовать данную задач? Может я велосипед изобретаю..?

Comment: Ну многие бы потянулись бы за слайдерами. Но для вашего примера такой реализации я считаю более чем достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А на `closest` не ругается ? [CanIUSe](http://caniuse.com/#search=closest). Попробуйте заменить этот кусок кода на аналог с `jquery`.

Также тут есть вот такая вот "деталь". "В Internet Explorer у объекта `window.event` для этого есть свойство `srcElement`, в остальных браузерах, работающих по рекомендациям W3C, для этого используется `event.target`." Взято с [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/properties)

И потому стоит заменить на что-то такое `var t = event.target || event.srcElement`

Набросал пример. Вроде сработало
https://jsfiddle.net/pm82od59/

Comment: Благодарю!!! :)